# Should all styles be ONLY in a .css file?

Tags: css

Should all styles be set in a .css file, or is it permissible to sometimes place styles right on the elements? For instance, when styling complex tables or when you want to add some extra styling to just one element among many using a certain class.

Comment: -1 for using "u" and not "you"

Comment: Those pesky CSS fiiles. Please take more care over your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can have them in the page, but it's preferable to have them in an external file so it can be cached by the browser. There's nothing wrong with combining the two techniques.

In your case you may have a class for in the external stylesheet, then you can have an in-page stylesheet that re-defines the same class. The one lower in the page takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb: **Always use classes and id's and avoid using the style attribute**.

This is because it makes your markup cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: +1 for mentioning maintainability -- one of the main reasons CSS was developed in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Styles go in the stylesheet. You don't want to be hunting in multiple places to debug your layouts, and even something that you only intend to use once is likely to get reused as requirements change.

Answer (score 0):

I generally follow this convention:

1. If the style is re-usable across multiple elements (such as color schemes), I create a class in a separate css file.
2. If the style is lengthy (e.g. 5 or more properties), I create a class in a separate file as well, to keep my html clean.
3. If there's only a couple properties for a specific element, it too much complexity to move it into a separate css file, and I leave it in the html.

edited to clarify #3

Comment: Reasonable, but could be messy if you reach a certain level of complexity. Maybe it's the better way then to explicitly avoid inline styles.